# Hash index for jumping to certain section on page is cutting part of the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a hash index for jumping to specific sections of the page. For instance, I created the following h2: `<h2 id="b2bvsb2c">B2B VS. B2C SEO</h2>`

So when I am navigating to the url: http://www.etraffic.co/seo-marketing-b2b-brands/#b2bvsb2c the page jumps directly to the point where is the h2 with the id "b2bvsb2c". The problem is that all the top of the page besides the header is being cut and I cant see the content above. Anyone knows what is happening?

I have a feeling that is some CSS bad rule but I am not sure...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's your code? Please read up on providing [mcve]s in questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
.single_posts { overflow: hidden }
```

Change to

```
.single_posts { overflow: scroll }
```

[Demo here](https://www.screencast.com/t/WLoWBqm8shdo)

Comment: Amazing man! I will do some tests yet before marking as answer. Thanks

Comment: I changed the overflow to scroll. But I am still having a problem with a space created below the content and now I am having 2 scrollbars....

Answer (score 0):

You can check the **overflow** style attribute in the following code css blocks:

```
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 75px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.single_posts {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

When overflow is not set to **hidden** this issue does not appear.